# Selenium WebDriver C# - get text

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, selenium, webdriver

I have this Html element on the page:

```
<li id="city" class="anketa_list-item">
   <div class="anketa_item-city">From</div>
    London
</li>
```

I found this element:

```
driver.FindElement(By.Id("city"))
```

If I try: `driver.FindElement(By.Id("city")).Text`, => my result: "From\r\nLondon".

How can I get only London by WebDriver?

Answer (score 15):

You could easily get by using `class-name`:

```
driver.FindElement(By.Class("anketa_item-city")).Text;
```

or using `Xpath`

```
driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("\li\div")).Text;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
var fromCityTxt = driver.FindElement(By.Id("city")).Text;
var city = Regex.Split(fromCityTxt, "\r\n")[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my misleading. My previous provide xpath is which ends in the function /text() which selects not a node, but the text of it.

Approach for this situation is get **parent's text** then **replace children's text** then **trim** to remove space/special space/etc ....

```
var parent = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//li"))
var child = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//li/div"))
var london = parent.Text.Replace(child.Text, "").Trim()
```

Notes:

If Trim() isn't working then it would appear that the "spaces" aren't spaces but some other non printing character, possibly tabs. In this case you need to use the String.Trim method which takes an array of characters:

```
char[] charsToTrim = { ' ', '\t' };
string result = txt.Trim(charsToTrim);
```

Comment: Exception: The given selector //li[@id='city']/text()[2] is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement. The following error occurred:
InvalidSelectorError: The result of the xpath expression "//li[@id='city']/text()[2]" is: [object XrayWrapper [object Text]]. It should be an element.

Comment: I've just updated my answer. Hope it could help ya

Sorry for any inconveniences may be caused

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//li[@id='city']/text()"));[image]